# Sigma 150-600mm + 1.4x TC

Tags: sigma, teleconverter, canon-5d-mark-iii

Am trying to get 1.4x extender for my Sigma 150-600 contemporary lens (canon Mount), would like to use it for wildlife / bird photography.

Camera am using: 5D Mark III (placed order for R5 - waiting on it :))

Does 1.4x TC works well on this lens?

If So which one should i get Canon 1.4x or Sigma 1.4x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Better get the Sigma, the lens is designed for it
2. The 1.4 TC will make it a 840mm lens, but also a F/9 lens. So:

   - The AF will struggle, assuming it works at all, forget it for birds in flight (but then, aiming at birds in flight with a 840mm lens requires a lot of training)...
   - Even with decent IS, you don't want to get too long exposures (especially on a dashing sparrow), you need all the light you can and the TC is taking some.

So IMHO, the TC will soon return to your bag (I have one, but I don't use it for wildlife...).

Comment: Yes I did order sigma 1.4x and waiting on it.  Will give a try, if doesn't works for me then goes into the bag.:)